# Transact SQL Returning Data based on foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have a table A that has two columns, each a foreign key to other tables where key data can be stored. need to pull back that key data such as name  based on those columns. Can do a left join to each table but that will include a lot of null values so want to avoid that. The foreign keys are not using nulls because a key could potentially exist for each value - but we do not use the system that way, so one field has a value the other a zero.

Example :

Table `A`:

```
Index  App   Ten
----------------
  1     123    0
  2     124    0
  3      0     125
  4      0     126
```

Table `App`:

```
Index  LName
---------------
 123     Jones
 124     Smith
```

Table `Ten`:

```
Index   Lname
---------------
 125      Doe
 126      Williams
```

What is the proper way to join these to select the table based on the index (ignore if zero) and return the data needed without left join and null values?

Desired output:

```
Index  App   Ten  Lname
------------------------------
  1     123    0    Jones
  2     124    0    Smith
  3      0     125  Doe
  4      0     126  Williams
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select A.Ind, A.App, A.Ten, coalesce(ap.LName,t.LName) 
from A 
LEFT JOIN App ap on ap.Ind = A.App 
LEFT JOIN Ten t on A.Ten = t.Ind
```

Coalesce will select the first value, if the first value is null, it will select the second value

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.[index], a.App, 0 as [Ten], App.Lname 
  from a 
  join App 
    on a.App = App.[Index] 
 where a.App <> 0
intersect 
select a.[index], 0 as [App], a.Ten, Ten.Lname 
  from a 
  join Ten
    on a.Ten = Ten.[Index] 
 where a.Ten <> 0
 order by 1
```

Get the values from App and then intersect them with Ten
<>  ignore the 0 vlues

Comment: I tried this an I got this err msg. `A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.` never seen that before but it was funny. From looking further into it, it seems its an indexing issue

Comment: While this might work, please provide some explanation on what it does, as SO isn't a site where you get a solution and leave. It should be a place to learn something. Currently, your answer is prone to Deletjolnir.

Comment: @LordZsolt That is complete syntax using names from the question.  SO is not a site where you repeat the documentation from MSDN.  Every bit of the syntax is covered more than thoroughly in the documentation.

Comment: @Blam Well OK, I was just telling you because your question was flagged as `Low Quality Post`. I came here from the Review, not from browsing SO.

Comment: @LordZsolt OK but I think that is a silly rules when the syntax uses the question table and column names

Comment: try [using] square braces around [reserved] words, like [index]